# Show multiple columns from database in one combobox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I want to show in one combobox content from two database columns. I would like to show "Name Surname" but I don't know how. I'm working in C# (.NET) using MVVM pattern. "Name" and "Surname" are fields from table "tblGuests".

Thanks in advance,
Vladimir

Answer (score 3):

You could create an ItemTemplate for the ComboBox that binds to all the properties you want to show.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        <DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

You could even create a UserControl that can be re-used and use that:

```
<PersonView>
    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</PersonView>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <PersonView/>
        <DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep a string list property in Viewmodel,

populate that property in a data loading method, by combining name and surname strings,

bind string property to combo box,

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding YourStringListProperty}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use MultiBinding something like this

```
<TextBlock Name="textBox2" DataContext="{StaticResource NameListData}">
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}"
                  ConverterParameter="FormatLastFirst">
      <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
      <Binding Path="LastName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

This code was taken directly from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx). Refer to it for more details